# Need to extract text from a PDF file with python

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to extract text from a PDF file, but it gives an error

```
PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file
```

Can anyone guide me with how to proceed with this?
Here is the code

```
import os
import PyPDF2

dir_name='path to folder'
files=os.listdir(dir_name)
os.chdir(dir_name)
for j in files:
     print(j)
     print("In file")
     pdfFileObj = open(j, 'rb')
     pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
     print(pdfReader.numPages)
     pdfFile=pdfReader.getPage(0)
       
     #page_lines=pdfFile.extractText()
     print(pdfFile.extractText())
       
     pdfFileObj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something which is happening cause of the files in the directory you did chdir.
Make sure it has no other files other than pdf files. Also try to extract files based on its extension, specially the ***.pdf***.
Here is similar code. Try executing it just for the files you found are malformed.

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
```

***Update***

It is observed that this module *PyPDF2* does not function properly. The module is only good for it's (.numPages) method. Other methods may or may not work as expected, while sometimes returning nothing.

Try *PdfMiner* for robust extraction. It has a lot of options to explore.
[pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer)

Comment: Hi, tried this but it returns an empty string. I mean it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you try doing the same by downloading the file given in this link.<https://github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/geeksforgeeks/blob/master/PyPDF2_tutorial/example.pdf>

Comment: Hi, it works for the pdf that I downloaded from the link. The pdf that I am trying to open is downloaded from a site and returns nothing.

Comment: The PDF that I download is digitally signed. Is the format unreadable due to which the text isn't extracted?

Comment: May be true. This code actually works for almost all the pdf's I have tested. Try fetching other pages. ```print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
print(pageObj.extractText())```

Comment: Hi Reema, I found a better solution. It's observed that this method ```pageObj.extractText())``` malfunctions. A better alternative is to use pdfminer. I have tested this and it's working gorgeous. Try this <https://github.com/euske/pdfminer>